# RecyclerView OnClick Implementation

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView to create a list, and i was suffering a lot, because i saw different ways to implement an OnClickListener, and comments says like very coupled, very tricky, etc.

And about several days thinking how to implement it, i did this.

On my Fragment, implement the View.OnClickListener and the onClickEvent and when i'm implementing the RecyclerView.Adapter pass the View.OnClickListener reference in the constructor, like this:

```
    public RecyclerViewRepoListAdapter(View.OnClickListener fragmentListener, List<Repos> repoList){
        if (repoList != null){
            this.reposList = repoList;
            this.fragmentListener = fragmentListener;
        }
    }
```

After that, when i'm creating the Holder to the different list components, i register the Listener to every (in this case) LinearLayout like this:

```
    @Override
    public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflate the corresponding layout
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_repositories, parent, false);
        //OnClickListener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(fragmentListener);
        //Here modify the view like margins, paddings, view size and layout parameters
        //return the ViewHolder
        return new ListItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

My cuestion is, what is your opinion about this implementation?

And if its ok, i hope this helps another one.

Comment: Yes it is ok if you do not want to do something to the clicked view

Comment: Actually that's what i do, because onClick receive the view was clicked like: onClick(View view){...} in this case a RelativeLayout

Comment: Yes you just get `view`, but without `position`

Comment: That's right!, some advice ,how could i get the position?

Comment: To get view position, you need implement `View.OnClickListener` in your ViewHolder, also one interface that pass view position needed and fragment/activity implements the interface. If this is not enough I can write answer but you need modify your question.